# Google Calendar API: attendees response status not updating when user respond to invite email

Tags: google-calendar-api

Good day all

I'm busy integrating the calendar API into my C# system and ran into a bit of a headache.

When I create an event, and I add attendees, they get their emails with the invite.
My issue comes, when they accept (or reject) the meeting, their responses are not captured.

In my event their response status always remain: NeedsAction

I have tested this directly via the Calendar API (https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) and I can get the event, I can see the attendees, yet their responseStatus does not change.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you please share your code? Or at least the request and response you make/get?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I tried mimicing the my code directly in the google calendar API, and I believe I happened upon the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the answer to the issue.

Basically what it comes down to, the person that accepts the invitation, needs to have a google calendar associated with their account.

What happened was I was sending the invite requests to my work email (that did not have an google account or calendar account associated with it).
I tested it again to my personal gmail, and viola! There it works perfectly.

Here is an image illustrating how the invite would appear in Microsoft Mail.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKPgN.jpg

If you accept there at the top option, the event would be added to your calendar, and potentially an email might be sent to the creator, but it does not get updated on the creator's google calendar. If you try to accept at the bottom, then you get a google error 400 page. This is what hinted me to what the issue was.